# How to emulate a box-shadow effect with overlapping elements and overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, overlap, box-shadow

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/janicewilson/pen/zjyeJe)

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    align-content: center;
    max-width: 50em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.cardWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cardWrapper:last-child,
.cardWrapper:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}

.card {
    width: 30em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 2em 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: $color-neutral95;
    border-radius: 1rem;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

Any ideas to either:

**( a )** Prevent the clipping of the box-shadow; or

**( b )** Emulate a box-shadow using another CSS property; or

**( c )** Go about this with a completely different approach?

I'm using React, and consequently prefer either a pure CSS or Javascript solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve this: https://codepen.io/vladimirlukyanov/pen/FwHbq

Comment: @makoi07 Thanks for the link. I'm after my implementation (side by side comparison with the plan I'm pushing always showing) with the hover effect that enables side-by-side comparison of the available plans. 

Specifically, I'd like creative suggestions to get overflow:hidden and box-shadow to play nicely together!